# Get list of API Management Custom domain

Tags: azure, shell, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I want to get the list of API Management custom domain but I didn't find any specific CLI command for it.

What is the best way to get the list of hostname and its certificate using Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Azure CLI and the --query option:

```
az apim show -g [your resource group] -n [your APIM tenant] --query "hostnameConfigurations[].{certificate:certificate, hostName:hostName}"
```

There does not seem to be a way to distinguish the default hostname object, other than knowing it will end with `.azure-api.net`

This uses CLI [Query Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli)
to examine particular child objects within the returned configuration.